# How to do smart sort in groovy?

Tags: sorting, groovy

I have a list of app versions which need to sort, but method sort() only counts the first digit.

Example:

```
def tags = ["3.3.1", "3.1.1", "2.2.1", "2.3.1", "3.2.1", "2.1.1"]
def sorted_tags = tags.sort().reverse()
return(sorted_tags)
// > ["3.3.1", "3.1.1", "3.2.1", "2.2.1", "2.1.1", "2.3.1"]
```

but i want to receive:

```
["3.3.1", "3.2.1", "3.1.1", "2.3.1", "2.2.1", "2.1.1"]
```

Comment: I took the liberty to fix your version strings in the list, but i am not sure, if that is your actual problem unless you are having versions like "2.10.X" this naive implementaion will work.

Comment: i have the versions like these: 2.10.9, 2.18.11 etc...

Comment: also i have some versions with characters like this  2.10.9-dev